# Sum SMTPE timecode in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime, time, sum

I have created an script in  PowerShell that queries a web service and returns an array of SMTPE time code duration's of video as shown:

### duration

00:00:12:24
00:00:13:11
00;00;00;00
00:00:13:11
00:00:13:11

I need to sum these together to output a total duration in SMPTE timecode format (HH:MM:SS:FF). Does anyone have any ideas where to start please?

(edited for clarity)

Comment: As this is my first post, can someone explain why my question is being down voted please?

Comment: I don't really know. But as for your example, why is there a time value that is all zero? In addition is the last bit supposed to be milliseconds or the first bit to be days? What did you try with that data to sum it? If the last bit isn't MS you might look into [`New-Timespan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan).

Comment: For the example data you have posted; what is the correct result? An explanation of the math involved would go a long way to you getting assistance

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a lot about the SMPTE timecode, I've given your question a bit of a stab.

Note that there are **some assumptions** made in this solution, as your question did not contain enough information to provide an accurate answer.

However, this should hopefully give you a steer in the right direction.

P.S. code deliberately verbose for ease of readability/adjustment:

```
<# hour:minute:second:frame #>

$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

# Mimic the results you provided
[array]$webServiceResults = @(
    "00:00:12:24",
    "00:00:13:11",
    "00;00;00;00",
    "00:00:13:11",
    "00:00:13:11"
)

# Configure your FPS here
[int]$framesPerSecond = 24

# Initialise some variables to kep a track of seconds and additional frames
[int]$totalSeconds = 0
[int]$frameCount = 0

# Loop over the results
foreach ($timecode in $webServiceResults) {
    # Sanity check the format... if it doesn't fit the pattern, ignore it!
    if ($timecode -like "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]") {
        # "parse" each portion of the string pattern
        [int]$hh = $timecode.Substring(0, 2)
        [int]$mm = $timecode.Substring(3, 2)
        [int]$ss = $timecode.Substring(6, 2)
        [int]$ff = $timecode.Substring(9, 2)

        # Some basic math
        $totalSeconds += ($hh * 60 * 60) + ($mm * 60) + ($ss)
        $frameCount += $ff
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "Invalid format = $timecode"
    }
}

# Calculate a final total number of frames.
[int]$totalFrames = ($totalSeconds * $framesPerSecond) + $frameCount

# Show results
Write-Host "TotalSeconds = $totalSeconds" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "FrameCount   = $frameCount" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "TotalFrames  = $totalFrames" -ForegroundColor Green
```